# Is it possible to create an A record for a global TLD?

Tags: domain-name-system

I have queried some TLDs through `dig`, and as I have expected, they all returned some information, such as SOA, NS, DNSSEC public keys and signatures. None of them contained any A, AAAA or CNAME records.

Is there a technical reason this is not possible, or is this just the policy of an organization such as ICANN preventing such registrations?

Comment: As in `dig com.`? Do `dig ai.` and you'll find some TLDs have A records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer myself: Yes, this is prohibited by ICANN [policy](https://www.icann.org/news/announcement-2013-08-30-en)

> The SSAC stated that dotless domains would not be universally reachable and recommended strongly against their use. As a result, the SSAC recommended that the use of DNS resource records such as A, AAAA, and MX in the apex of a Top-Level Domain (TLD) should be contractually prohibited where appropriate, and strongly discouraged in all cases.

Comment: `.pn`, `.dk`, `.ai`, `.ws` and [a variety of others](http://blog.towo.eu/a-records-on-top-level-domains/) have A records.

Comment: Thank you for the link, so it seems those domains are violating the policy adopted by the ICANN three years after the publication of this blog

Comment: I'd bet ICANN doesn't really care much. It's silly to do - no one's likely to type 'em in like this, there's not much point to having it, and it'd be confusing for users to market something like `http://com/`. Self-solving problem, no need to do a legal crackdown.

Comment: @ceejayoz I suppose they don't have much say when it comes to the ccTLDs, but I'd think they actually do care. Especially when it comes to the registration of new gTLDs I can imagine how it could become the "new cool thing" to use your own TLD like that.

Comment: Doubt it. If I type "ws" or "ai" into Chrome it goes to a Google search. I have to type the full `http://...` for it to attempt to go to the actual record. Not much fun to tell potential customers they have to type the full thing.

Comment: gTLD registries are under contracts with ICANN (ccTLDs are not) and in their contract there are clauses defining what they can put at apex of their zone. See Exhibit A section 1.1 of https://newgtlds.icann.org/sites/default/files/agreements/agreement-approved-31jul17-en.html